# Condition display metabox in case the post is saved

Tags: metabox, conditional-content, publish

I need to register a metabox in my WordPress custom post, but only in case the post is permanent saved in database.

What I mean, when the user click on "Add new" I don't want to display the metabox. When the user click on "Publish" after the page refresh display the metabox.

The post status doesn't matter (published, private or what ever)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to @m0r7if3r's solution, the `add_meta_boxes` hook optionally passes two variables, the post type and post object. You can use this to conditionally add your metabox. New posts have the post status of 'auto-draft'.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box',10,2);
function myplugin_add_custom_box($post_type, $post) {
    if($post->post_status != 'auto-draft'){
        add_meta_box( 
         'myplugin_sectionid',
         __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
         'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
         'post' );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 really solid solution...I'd be interested to see if it outperformed mine in real-world usage.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to filter the call to `add_meta_box()` conditionally using the `$current_screen` variable or `get_current_screen()`. The only time that the user shouldn't see the box is on `post-new.php`, once they leave that page, some form of saving has been done.

Comment: How to use the $current_screen, and the get_current_screen(). Any tutorial? I user the $current_screen with global $current_screen; echo $current_screen and I get no response, and I user the get_current_screen() and I get a PHP error, function not exists :(

Comment: You can view what's in `$current_screen` with `print_r()`. It's not available until after the `admin_head` hook though, so make sure you're hooking into `admin_head` or something around there.